# Argument of type 'x | y' is not assignable to parameter of type 'x & y'

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an enum called `ServiceType`. For each enum-value — each service — there's a corresponding configuration interface, and a corresponding command-builder function that takes an instance of the configuration interface and builds a command object for calling the service.

I *want* to have a `getCommandBuilder` function that takes an enum-value and returns the corresponding command-builder function; but the problem is, TypeScript expects the argument to the command-builder function to implement *all* of the configuration interfaces, instead of just the relevant one based on the enum-value.

Here's a small example showing the idea:

```
const enum ServiceType {
    SERVICE_1,
    SERVICE_2,
}

interface Service1Config {
    field1: string;
}

interface Service2Config {
    field2: number;
}

const commandBuilder1 = (_: Service1Config) : void => {}

const commandBuilder2 = (_: Service2Config) : void => {}

const getCommandBuilder = (serviceType: ServiceType) => {
    switch (serviceType) {
        case ServiceType.SERVICE_1:
            return commandBuilder1
        case ServiceType.SERVICE_2:
            return commandBuilder2
    }
}

const myServiceType = ServiceType.SERVICE_1
const myServiceConfig = {field1: "Type one"} as Service1Config

const myCommandBuilder = getCommandBuilder(myServiceType)

myCommandBuilder(myServiceConfig)   // ERROR!
```

(In my real code there's an array with all the different service-types and service-configs that I'm looping over, so I can't just hardcodedly write `myCommandBuilder = commandBuilder1`.)

This is the error that TypeScript gives for the above example:

```
example.ts:32:18 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Service1Config' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Service1Config & Service2Config'.
  Property 'field2' is missing in type 'Service1Config' but required in type 'Service2Config'.
```

How can I get TypeScript to understand that the function returned by `getCommandBuilder(ServiceType.SERVICE_1)` just needs a `Service1Config` argument, and the function returned by `getCommandBuilder(ServiceType.SERVICE_2)` just needs a `Service2Config` argument?

Comment: Could you condense that code into a single self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  Or, barring that, add a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates your issue?  Right now others would have to do work just to try to get to the starting point, which makes it less likely that you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ruakh I have added the example in the edit.

Comment: @jcalz I have added the example in the edit.